# How is loot shared on D3 console co-op?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have read that Blizzard have built the console version from the ground up and that they have made a few changes to the loot mechanic.

Is there any difference to how loot is shared in the console version in co-op?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From an [FAQ on the Blizzard forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9280998875):

> > **Q: How does looting work on the console version?**
> >
> > A: It’s not all that different from PC, with just a few exceptions. For example, loot is shared between local players (so ‘first come, first serve’). It’ll still work the same for online players, though – meaning if you’re being matched into an online game, your loot will be personal. You only share loot with players playing on your same machine. (Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9244644870#4 )

So only when playing local co-op will there be any difference.

Comment: Technically you can't play multiple characters on the same pc.  Its only different because there isn't share loot AT ALL on PC.